# Tensorflow 'features' format

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

I'm a total begginer with AI and tensorflow, so please forgive if this is a dumb question.
I've trained a tensorflow network using a script based on this tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html

I believe training was ok.
Now I whant to run this method to make a prediction for a single input:

```
tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier.predict_proba(x=x)
```

But I cannot find any documentation on how to build the "x" parameter...
I tryed:

```
 x = {k: tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0]], values=[d_data[k]], shape=[1, 1]) for k in COLUMNS}
```

Where:
**d_data** is a dictionary containing about 150 key/value pairs.
**COLUMNS** is a list with all the keys needed. 
This same setup was used to train the network.

But got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

So... x should not be a 'dict'... but what should it be then?
Can anyone give me some directions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BaseEstimator class has better [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5c44302d778f43a13bf1b97bffd0b2b6be46ae2f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L369).

```
x: Matrix of shape [n_samples, n_features...]. Can be iterator that returns arrays of features. The training input samples for fitting the model. If set, `input_fn` must be `None`.
```

I will looking into getting the documentation here fixed. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but I think this is because we are using an older release of tensorflow (I am on 0.8.0) and the fit method now can take a different input type 'input_fn' which I think can take the form of a dictionary, see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5c44302d778f43a13bf1b97bffd0b2b6be46ae2f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L197)

```
  def fit(self, x=None, y=None, input_fn=None, steps=None, batch_size=None,
      monitors=None, max_steps=None):
```

In my current release this function doesn't have 'input_fn', hence why it is mandatory to input a tensor matrix object as x.

Did you manage to find a solution in the meantime?